# Count the number of records for each 1st of the month in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a dataset where I would like to query and obtain output of a count of records for the first of every month.

**Data**

```
 name      date1
 hello     july 1 2018
 hello     july 1 2018
 hello     july 10 2018
 sure      august 1 2019
 sure      august 1 2019
 why       august 20 2019
 ok        september 1 2019
 ok        september 1 2019
 ok        september 1 2019
 sure      september 5 2019
```

**Desired**

```
ID   MONTH       Day    YEAR
2    July        1      2018
2    August      1      2019
3   September    1      2019
```

We are only counting the records from the 1st of each month

**Doing**

```
USE [Data]
SELECT    COUNT(*) AS ID , MONTH(date1) AS MONTH, YEAR(date1) AS YEAR
FROM      dbo.data1
GROUP BY  MONTH(date1), YEAR(date1)
ORDER BY YEAR ASC
```

This only outputs the year and month
Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: You need to show some sample starting data, because its not clear what the problem is.

Comment: If you want a count, why doesn't your desired result have a count column of some sort?

Comment: Count is under 'ID' column

Comment: A simple approach is to filter for `DAY(date1) = 1` (with other adjustments I leave to you). But this strikes me as a very strange goal and I suspect there is more to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the implicit conversion for date

**Example**

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS ID, 
        DATENAME(MONTH,date1) AS MONTH, 
        DATEPART(DAY,date1) as DAY,
        YEAR(date1) AS YEAR
FROM    dbo.data1
WHERE  DAY(date1)=1
GROUP BY YEAR(date1),DATENAME(MONTH,date1),DATEPART(DAY,date1)
ORDER BY YEAR ASC
```

**Results**

```
ID  MONTH       DAY     YEAR
2   July        1       2018
2   August      1       2019
3   September   1       2019
```

Comment: Thanks @john this works perfectly. I was troubleshooting earlier, but this is the solution

Comment: @Lynn Is DATE1 actually stored as a string like "july 1 2018"?   This is risky, because it would be easy to get bogus data.

Comment: @Lynn Not according to your "Data" description.